# Name-value and key-value pairs both being created in PHP file (for json encode)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, key-value

I am generating PHP arrays from a MySQL database, with the output to be converted to JSON using json_encode (ultimately for use with Twitter typeahead).

Based upon everything I've read about PHP arrays, I had expected the `select` query to generate - for any record - just a single key-value pair for each column.

Instead, I seem to be getting **both** a **name-value pair** and a **key-value pair**.

For instance, for a table with 5 columns, the set of values FOR A SINGLE RECORD are in the form:

```
[fieldname1] => value1 [0] => value1
[fieldname2] => value2  [1] => value2
[fieldname3]] => value3 [2] => value3 
[fieldname4]=> value4  [3] => value4 
[fieldname5] => value5 [4] => value5
```

When I use json_encode it generates the following JSON string for that record - which is twice as long as it needs to be because I am getting both the name-value pair and the key-value pair (so the the value is repeated very line).

```
"fieldname1":"value1","0":"value1",
"fieldname2":"value2","1":"value2",
"fieldname3":"value3","2":"value3",
"fieldname4":"value4","3":"value4",
"fieldname5":"value5","4":"value5",
```

What I would prefer is just the `'fieldname1' => 'value1'` or its json equivalent.

Here is an example of the code I use in PHP to select the data from the database.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tr_trades_anzsco` WHERE `trade_alias_id` > 898";
$trade = $dbh->query($sql);

    foreach($trade as $trade):  
            $trade_alias_id = $trade['trade_alias_id'];
            $trade_alias = trim($trade['trade_alias']);
            print_r($trade);
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Here is the resultant dataset for just three records.

```
Array ( [trade_alias_id] => 899 [0] => 899 [trade_alias] => Boilermaker [1] => Boilermaker [ANZSCO_title] => Structural Steel And Welding Trades Workers [2] => Structural Steel And Welding Trades Workers [ANZSCO_code] => 322300 [3] => 322300 [source] => Raj [4] => Raj ) Array ( [trade_alias_id] => 900 [0] => 900 [trade_alias] => Welder [1] => Welder [ANZSCO_title] => Structural Steel And Welding Trades Workers [2] => Structural Steel And Welding Trades Workers [ANZSCO_code] => 322300 [3] => 322300 [source] => Tom [4] => Tom ) Array ( [trade_alias_id] => 901 [0] => 901 [trade_alias] => Rigger [1] => Rigger [ANZSCO_title] => Construction Rigger [2] => Construction Rigger [ANZSCO_code] => 821711 [3] => 821711 [source] => Jack [4] => Jack )
```

Finally, here is the json string for the final record only (broken up so the structure is more easily visible).

```
Array ( [0] => Array (
[trade_alias_id] => 901 [0] => 901
[trade_alias] => Rigger [1] => Rigger 
[ANZSCO_title] => Construction Rigger [2] => Construction Rigger 
[ANZSCO_code] => 821711 [3] => 821711 
[source] => Jack [4] => Jack )
)
```

The duplicate values matter considerably for performance reasons - because the data is to be extracted for use on mobile devices (with Twitter TypeAhead and possibly AngulularJS). Our datasets are already very large ... so twice the json will double the time for fetching the data.

**Key question: How I can remove the duplicates either at the PHP stage OR the json_encode stage so as to generate ONLY a name-value pair but not both a name-value and a key-value pair?**

Thank you!

Comment: How are you reaching MySQL (mysql_*, mysqli_*, PDO)? And how are you fetching the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you are using pdo:

```
$trade = $dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset it if the key is int

```
foreach($trade as $key=>$value) {
   if(!is_int($key) {
      unset($trade[$key]);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly where I put this code?  It sounds right - but I don't know how to use it correctly.  I tried placing it below the initial foreach block, but that didn't work (and just resulted in a "T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM" error).      Should I haved nested your block of code within the existing foreach?

Comment: place it before the initial foreach. It will rewrite the $trade that comes straight from the DB

Comment: :)) the error is because of `$key=>value` it's a parse error indeed :D it should be `$key=>$value` . remember: it's always about the $